# which is correct "I no longer eat it now" or " I wouldn't eat it now"

Tags: grammar

a) I used to like fish, but I no longer eat it now
or
b) I used to like fish, but I wouldn't eat it now

I think we can't use "no longer" with now because now is a moment unlike if we said nowadays am I correct?

Comment: 'Now' can be an undefined period which you could call 'the present time'. I used to get drunk when I was 18, but I no longer do that now. '‘Now we have her no longer’: the crowds on the Queen’s final journey' - The Guardian

Comment: _I no longer eat it_ means that you don't eat it any more. _I wouldn't eat it_ means that you would refuse it even if someone cooked some for you.

Comment: Are you asking whether it's correct to use "no longer" with "now"? Your two sentences mean different things, so we can't choose which one is correct.

Comment: 'Jesus Lives! No Longer Now Can Thy Terrors, Death, Appall Us; Jesus Lives!' - Christ My Song (hymn) 1860; 'No longer now/He slays the lamb that looks him in the face/And horribly devours his mangled flesh' (poem, _Queen Mab_, Percy Bysshe Shelley). Shelley was a vegetarian.

Comment: so both are grammatically correct? ok thanks. it was a question in my homework but it's from an obscure book I guess it's wrong